# Why is requirements.txt not being installed on deployment to AppEngine?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pip, requirements.txt

I'm attempting to upgrade an existing project to the new Python 3 AppEngine Standard Environment. I'm able to deploy my application code, however the app is crashing because it can not find dependencies that are defined in the requirements.txt file. The app file structure looks likes this:

```
|____requirements.txt
|____dispatch.yaml
|____dashboard
| |____dashboard.yaml
| |____static
| | |____gen
| | | |____favicon.ico
| | | |____fonts
| | | | |____MaterialIcons-Regular.012cf6a1.woff
| | | |____app.js
| | |____img
| | | |____avatar-06.png
| | | |____avatar-07.png
| | | |____avatar-05.png
| | | |____avatar-04.png
| |____templates
| | |____gen
| | | |____index.html
| |____main.py
| |____.gcloudignore
|____.gcloudignore
```

And the `requirements.txt` file looks like this:

```
Flask==0.12.2
pyjwt==1.6.1
flask-cors==3.0.3
requests==2.19.1
google-auth==1.5.1
pillow==5.3.0
grpcio-tools==1.16.1
google-cloud-storage==1.13.0
google-cloud-firestore==0.30.0
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
Werkzeug<0.13.0,>=0.12.0
firestore-model>=0.0.2
```

After deploying, when I visit the site on the web, I get a 502. The GCP Console Error Reporting service indicates the error is thrown from a line in `main.py` where it attempts to import one of the above dependencies: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'`

I've tried moving the `requirements.txt` into the dashboard folder and get the same result.

Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 104, in init_process
    super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/srv/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from google.cloud import storage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace? Also which directory are you deploying the app from?

Comment: I've been deploying from the top level, the same level as requirements.txt. Added stacktrace to question.

Comment: The `requirements.txt` should be in the same directory as `main.py`, and you should be deploying from that directory. Does the same error happen when you deploy from there? Also is it possible your `.gcloudignore` is ignoring the `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Looks like both of your suggestions have helped to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I added an answer to that effect, please accept if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things could be going wrong. Make sure that:

- Your `requirements.txt` file is in the same directory as your `main.py` file
- Your `.gcloudignore` is not ignoring your `requirements.txt` file
- You are deploying the function this same directory as `requirements.txt` and `main.py`